# Send user to Homepage automatically after verifying email - Flutter-Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, email

In my app, after a user signs up, they receive a verification email. Once they verify their email and come back to the app, I want them to be automatically taken to the homepage without having to click anything or restart the app. How can I make this happen?

I have tried using `authStateChanges`:

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I have not done this myself but I know there is a way called universal links and I think flutter has it too. try searching it if you don't get answer you want. sorry if I'm not too helpful

Comment: @NIMAShahahmadian Thanks!, It is possible with flutter, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can try this:

1. **Firebase Auth Listener**: Set up an authentication state listener in your Flutter app. This listener should be active on the 'Verify Your Email' page.
2. **Check Email Verification Status**: Within the listener, check if the user's email has been verified. This can be done by checking the `emailVerified` property of the Firebase user object.
3. **Redirect to Homepage**: If the `emailVerified` property is true, use Flutter's navigator to redirect the user to the homepage. This redirection should happen automatically without requiring any user interaction.

Here's the code snippet for doing this:

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user != null && user.emailVerified) {
      // Redirect to the homepage
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/homepage');
    }
  });
```

It listens for changes in the authentication state. When the user's email is verified, it automatically navigates to the homepage.
I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, any idea how I will use this snippet?

Comment: Hey @Saad, the snippet I provided for redirecting users to the homepage after email verification, you should place it in a location where it can actively monitor the authentication state as soon as the app is running and the user is likely to complete the email verification process.

Answer (score 0):

This code will send a verification email to the user's email address. The email will contain a link that the user must click on to verify their email address.

```
Future<void> sendVerificationEmail() async {
 final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  await user.sendEmailVerification();
}
```

This code will automatic redirection to the homepage after email verification.

```
Future<void> verifyEmail(BuildContext context) async {
    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    user.reload();
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      // Navigate to the homepage
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logical code or shorter code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

return StreamBuilder(
  stream: _auth.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      User? user = snapshot.data as User?;
      if (user == null) {
        // User is not signed in
        return SignInScreen();
      } else {
        // Check if the user's email is verified
        if (user.emailVerified) {
          // User is signed in and email is verified, navigate to the homepage
          return HomeScreen();
        } else {
          // User is signed in but email is not verified, show verification screen
          return VerifyEmailScreen();
        }
      }
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticationWrapperState createState() => _AuthenticationWrapperState();
}

class _AuthenticationWrapperState extends State<AuthenticationWrapper> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _auth.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          User? user = snapshot.data as User?;
          if (user == null) {
            // User is not signed in
            return SignInScreen();
          } else {
            // Check if the user's email is verified
            if (user.emailVerified) {
              // User is signed in and email is verified, navigate to the homepage
              return HomeScreen();
            } else {
              // User is signed in but email is not verified, show verification screen
              return VerifyEmailScreen();
            }
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}

class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sign In"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // Perform sign-in logic here
          },
          child: Text("Sign In"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Welcome to the homepage!"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VerifyEmailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Verify Email"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Please verify your email to access the homepage."),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // Send email verification link
                User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                await user?.sendEmailVerification();
              },
              child: Text("Resend Verification Email"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```